# Artin-Wedderburn baby version

Tags: modules, group-homomorphism, module-isomorphism

I am trying to show that if $R \cong M_n(D)$ as rings where $D$ is a division ring, then $R \cong S \oplus … \oplus S$ where $S$ is a simple left $R$-module (isomorphic as modules)

I know that $M_n(D)= C_1 \oplus …\oplus C_n $ where $C_i$ is the ith column with zeroes everywhere else. Each $C_i$ is isomorphic as modules to $D^n$ which is simple as a left $M_n(D) $ module and so each $C_i $ is a simple left ideal in $M_n(D)$.

So letting $\phi :M_n (D) \rightarrow R $ be a ring isomorphism we have $\phi (R)= \phi (C_1 \oplus … \oplus C_n)= \phi (C_1) \oplus … \oplus \phi (C_n) $ and each $\phi (C_i ) $ is a simple left ideal in $R$. But now what I need to show is that each $\phi (C_i )$ is isomorphic to each other as **modules** and then that would complete the proof but I don’t know how to show this final part.

Comment: Won't they be free of the same rank?  Does that do it?

Comment: Does that show that they’re isomorphic as modules?

Comment: Yes:  two free modules of the same rank are isomorphic.

Comment: This is essentially just a part of the explanation of your last question on the topic. I've expanded the solution there to address your comment/this question.  Please be patient and avoid spreading a question out over multiple posts, even if you feel like you are not getting answers fast enough.